# Gradle Dependency error while implementing LDAP Authentication using Spring Security

Tags: java, gradle, spring-security, ldap

I am getting the below two errors even after having the below dependencies in build.gradle :

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.ldap', name: 'spring-ldap-core', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-ldap', version: '4.0.4.RELEASE'
```

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.ldap.core.ContextSource   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 26 common
>   frames omitted

or

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.security.ldap.search.LdapUserSearch   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 26 common
>   frames omitted

Can you please help me with this error , is there a versioning conflict between the dependencies here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed looks like a versioning conflict. According to [MVNRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-ldap/4.0.4.RELEASE), `spring-security-ldap 4.0.4.RELEASE` depends on spring-ldap-core 2.0.2.RELEASE version.

I think you can safely remove the dependency for `spring-ldap-core` and see that resolves your problem.

While you're at it, you may think about upgrading to a later version too.

Comment: Hi MuratOzkan, I removed the "spring-ldap-core" dependency as suggested and i still receive an error "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.ldap.search.LdapUserSearch"

Comment: What other dependencies you have?

Comment: MuratOzkan , The dependencies provided above were of the parent build.gradle , there are numerous other dependencies in the child module.
I just added the above dependency to the child module build.gradle and it worked fine , thanks.